# Optimizing code for reading in multiple files from CDF format and into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cdf

```
#Code for Defined Function, returning pandas dataframe
    def convert_cdfs_to_dataframe(filelist, varlist):
#import spacepy and delorean for cdfs and datetimes
    from spacepy import pycdf
    from delorean import Delorean

#create empty numpy arrays
    ll=len(varlist); varsdata=[np.zeros(1) for i in range(ll+1)]
# read data from cdf files and append the arrays.
    for i in filelist:
        print 'reading file '+i
        d = pycdf.CDF(i)
        for j in varlist:
            idx=varlist.index(j)
            varsdata[idx]= np.append(varsdata[idx], pycdf.VarCopy(d[j]))
    print 'Done reading data'
#   For create an epoch array from Epoch2
#   (s)econds (s)ince (epoch) == ssepoch
    idxe = varlist.index('Epoch2'); ldata=len(varsdata[0]); ssepoch=np.zeros(ldata)
    for i in range(1,ldata):
        ssepoch[i] = Delorean(varsdata[idxe][i],timezone="UTC").epoch 
        # drop the first zero before creating the data frame
        dictionary = {}; dictionary['time']=ssepoch[1:]
        for j in varlist:
            if j == 'Epoch2':
                dictionary['datetime']=varsdata[varlist.index(j)][1:]
            else:
                dictionary[j] = varsdata[varlist.index(j)][1:]
# create a pandas dataframe
    d = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
# drop the missing data values (999. for Voyager) by np.NaN
    d.replace(to_replace=999.,value=np.NaN,inplace=True)
    return d
```

> The main question...Are there ways to improve the running time of the code >above, or is this pretty much as fast as it gets?  The code works fine, but just >trying to find a more efficient way to read in the files. The parameter varlist >contains strings that are the labeled titles for certain columns of data in the >CDF files.  The filelist is just a collection of directories to certain file(s) >in string format.  Thank you for any and all assistance regarding this issue!

Comment: It would help if you post some example files (or link to a few) and provide your timings (`%timeit functionname(inputs)` from the ipython interface is easiest).  Better yet to profile the whole thing it will point out which parts of your code need optimizing.  Just looking at your above code and optimizations I've done it the past, excessive loops usually are time killers.  Also if I recall `np.append` isn't that fast

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment, Matt!  I found the time for the function and with best of 3, it was 4.62 seconds running time.  Also, the Main part for optimization would be replacing the 2 for loops for something else with same results, but faster speed, for when I am converting the times using Delorean, which is responsible for most of the running time in function.  I will research into other faster ways than np.append, however, I do believe that using numpy arrays is faster than using lists. Thanks again!

Comment: I would also like to add that the running time I gave was for a single file directory, which contains a few days worth of data taken every 2 seconds.

Comment: Your code produces "IndentationError: unexpected indent" because of your comments.  Can you clean that up?

Comment: Nealmcb, that actually doesnt create an indent error because everything is under an if-statement further above thats not shown, so the indents are okay as they are, its more of the actually flow of the code that im sure can be more efficient, just not sure how, thank you!!!